# Xcode Analyzer Leak Warning When Updating Property

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have the below method that returns the `NSFileWrapper` for my `NSDocument` subclass.

I am getting an Analyzer warning on `image` saying that the *"allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of"*.

This is absolutely true, however I am updating a property with `image` and if I call `CGImageRelease(image)` I will get a crash as I do use it outside of this methods scope.

Any ideas on how to get rid of this warning? I'm I overlooking something obvious?

```
- (NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapperOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {
    CGImageRef image = PCCreateImageFromLayer(self.myLayer, self.myLayerSize, 1.0);
    self.project.previewImage = image;
    return self.project.fileWrapper;
}
```